# How can I make an image continue across multiple sections with breaks in between?

Tags: html, css, image, styles

I'm working with some simple HTML and CSS, but I can't figure out how to achieve the effect I'm going for. [Here's how it looks right now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7fwU.png) The background image is the background for a container section and each red box is a section within that container. I like that the background image is continuous across the boxes (i.e. doesn't repeat), but I'd like it to not show up in the space between the boxes. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: When you say "Between the boxes", is that all areas outside the red border? What about the lower right area - should it have the background, or not?  There's several ways to solve this, but this detail is significant

Comment: There's actually going to be another box there, [like this.](http://i.imgur.com/JZeRMjz.png) I'd like the background to fill up all 3 boxes. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of solutions, depending on the details of what you want:

If the spaces are going to be small, and you want the background everywhere on the entire page, you could use css to apply borders to your boxes, which will render "on top of" the background you have applied.  Putting a border-right on the "TEAM" div, and a border-bottom on the upper-right div, would create the "separation" you're talking about.

If you want the background only in the sections outlined in red, you might consider removing the background from the element behind, and apply it to each div separately.  By using background-position, you can cause the background to appear like one solid piece, separated only by the space between the boxes.

Example pseudo-css:

```
div.team,
div.top_right,
div.bottom_right {
    background: transparent url(image/my_bg_image.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;
}

div.top_right {
    background-position: -500px 0; /* assumes the team div was 500px wide */
}

div.bottom_right {
    background-position: -500px -250px; /* assumes the top_right div is 250px tall */
}
```